# How can I record data related to http responses in Laravel?

Tags: http, laravel, httpresponse

I wanted to keep records of the http responses my server is throwing. So, for example, for each server request, I would like to record if the http response was a 1xx response, or a 2xx, 3xx and so on. At the end of the day, I would like to see, for example, that from the 1000 requests, 2% of them are a 5xx server error responses. I’m using the laravel framework.

I don’t want to redirect the responses, nor change the response messages. I just want to keep records of them.
How could I achieve that? I'm not sure in which point of the laravel model I should introduce my logic. Where to intercept the final response?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Would using "after filters" be the answer?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Are you just wanting to store a count and no other information?

Comment: Also would it not just be easier to retrieve the information from your server logs. You could write a simple log parser to do this if your just interested in the response codes.

Comment: @Jeemusu, I'm using Laravel 5.0.

Comment: @Mark Davidson, that's correct, I just want a counter to count the kind and frequency of http responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I have three options.

1. (in my opinion, the best option) As mentioned by @mark-davidson, one solution is to use the server logs.
2. One can also use middleware "after" to achieve that, as mentioned by @peterpan666.
3. Reading the laravel documentation I just found out about the middleware "terminator", which could also be a good option, since this middleware runs only after the response is sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global middleware "after", see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#defining-middleware

Then check the response

- if it's an instance of `\Illuminate\Http\Response`, you have a `status()` method on it that gives you the response status.
- If it's not a Response instance then it should be a `200 OK` status.

Comment: what about the routes in which I have a "middleware before". In those cases, would the "middleware after" catch these responses?

Comment: Well yeah, that's the beauty of middlewares ;)